# Read multiple excel files from a folder into pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to read several excel files contained into a folder in the Desktop of my MacBook into pandas.

The folder in the desktop is contains a folder (project dataset) with all the excel files and the Jupiter notebook page where I am writing the code (draft progetto)

I wrote the following code:

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files
```

Output:

```
['.DS_Store', 'draft progetto.ipynb', '.ipynb_checkpoints', 'project_dataset']
```

Then when I run:

```
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[3:] == 'xlsx']
files_xls
```

I GET AN EMPTY LIST AS OUTPUT!! 
WHY IS THIS?

Comment: what#s the output of `f[3:]` did you try printing it? what version of python are you on ?

Comment: i cannot see any file having `xlsx` file in your list?

Comment: they are contained in the 'project_dataset' folder @anky_91

Comment: you need to specify the right path - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

this is something that can be done much easier with `pathlib` and `unix` matching using the `glob` module.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

#one liner
your_path = 'path_to_excel_files'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in Path(your_path).rglob('*.xlsx')])
```

### Breaking it down.

```
# find the excel files 
# if you want to change the path do Path('your_path')...
files = [file for file in Path.cwd.rglob('*.xlsx')]

#create a list of dataframes.
dfs_list = [pd.read_excel(file) for file in files])


#concat
df = pd.concat(dfs_list)
```

Comment: I think I have a problem in determining the path to the excel file, what I would do is: your_path = ' Desktop/Folder/project_dataset'

Comment: @stud_eco I've added in a recursive method from the pathlib class `rglob` This is like calling `Path.glob() with “**/”` added in front of the given relative pattern: